# Cannot get both radio buttons to pass values to ObaservableList Java?

Tags: java

I am in the process of learning Java and I can't seem to make this function work. I am working on a project for an inventory system. Where parts are added to an observable list. In the add part screen, I have two radio buttons to select whether the part is an InHouse made or OutSourced. I have an if statement using a toggle group to check which radio button is selected. I was trying to use an else statement to pass the values if it was an outsourced part. Right now it will pass the values correctly if the radio button is set to InHouse, but when set to Outsource it throws a null pointer exception at the line the if statement is on.

Here is the code I am trying to make work.

```java
package ViewController;

import Model.InHouse;
import Model.Inventory;
import Model.OutSource;
import Model.Part;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class AddPart implements Initializable {
    public RadioButton addPartInHouse;
    public TextField partIDTxtbox;
    public TextField partNameTxtbox;
    public TextField invTxtbox;
    public TextField pricePerUnitTxtbox;
    public TextField maxQtyTxtbox;
    public TextField minQtyTxtbox;
    public Button addPartSaveButton;
    public Button addPartCancelButton;
    public RadioButton addPartOutSource;
    public Label companyNameLabel;
    public TextField companyNamePrompt;
    public ToggleGroup switchfield;



    public void addPartInHouse(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        companyNameLabel.setText("Machine ID");
        companyNamePrompt.setPromptText("Machine ID");
        addPartOutSource.setSelected(false);

    }

    public void addPartOutsource(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        companyNameLabel.setText("Company Name");
        companyNamePrompt.setPromptText("Company Name");
        addPartInHouse.setSelected(false);
    }

    public void addPartSaveButton(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {

/*this is my line 55 below*/ 
        if (this.switchfield.getSelectedToggle().equals(this.addPartInHouse)) {
            Part partadd = new InHouse(0, "", 0.0, 0,0,0,0);
            if(partIDTxtbox.getText().isEmpty()){
                partadd.setPartID(Inventory.getPartIDCount());
            }
            if (!partNameTxtbox.getText().isEmpty()){
                partadd.setPartName(partNameTxtbox.getText());
            }
            if (!pricePerUnitTxtbox.getText().isEmpty()){
                partadd.setPartPrice(Double.parseDouble(pricePerUnitTxtbox.getText()));
            }
            if (!invTxtbox.getText().isEmpty()){
                partadd.setPartInStock(Integer.parseInt(invTxtbox.getText()));
            }
            if(!minQtyTxtbox.getText().isEmpty()){
                partadd.setMin(Integer.parseInt(minQtyTxtbox.getText()));
            }
            if(!maxQtyTxtbox.getText().isEmpty()){
                partadd.setMax(Integer.parseInt(maxQtyTxtbox.getText()));
            }
            if(!companyNamePrompt.getText().isEmpty()){
                ((InHouse)partadd).setMachineID(Integer.parseInt(companyNamePrompt.getText()));
            }
            Inventory.addPart(partadd);
        }
        else{
            Part partaddout = new OutSource(0, "", 0.0, 0,0,0,"");
            if(partIDTxtbox.getText().isEmpty()){
                partaddout.setPartID(Inventory.getPartIDCount());
            }
            if (!partNameTxtbox.getText().isEmpty()){
                partaddout.setPartName(partNameTxtbox.getText());
            }
            if (!pricePerUnitTxtbox.getText().isEmpty()){
                partaddout.setPartPrice(Double.parseDouble(pricePerUnitTxtbox.getText()));
            }
            if (!invTxtbox.getText().isEmpty()){
                partaddout.setPartInStock(Integer.parseInt(invTxtbox.getText()));
            }
            if(!minQtyTxtbox.getText().isEmpty()){
                partaddout.setMin(Integer.parseInt(minQtyTxtbox.getText()));
            }
            if(!maxQtyTxtbox.getText().isEmpty()){
                partaddout.setMax(Integer.parseInt(maxQtyTxtbox.getText()));
            }
            if(!companyNamePrompt.getText().isEmpty()){
                ((OutSource)partaddout).setCompanyName((companyNamePrompt.getText()));
            }
            Inventory.addPart(partaddout);
        }
        Parent addPartSave = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainScreen.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(addPartSave);
        Stage window = (Stage) ((Node) e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }

    public void addPartCancelButton(MouseEvent mouseEvent) throws IOException {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Cancel add part");
        alert.setHeaderText("You are about to return to the Main screen!");
        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();

        if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
            Parent addPartCancel = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainScreen.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(addPartCancel);
            Stage window = (Stage) ((Node) mouseEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            window.setScene(scene);
            window.show();
        }
        else{
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        switchfield = new ToggleGroup();
        this.addPartInHouse.setToggleGroup(switchfield);

    }
}
'''
```

Comment: [edit] your question and post the full stack trace of your `NullPointerException`

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ViewController.AddPart.addPartSaveButton(AddPart.java:55)
 ... 58 more

Comment: Click on this link: [edit]  and add your **full** stack trace to your question. Also indicate which line of your code is line 55 (in file `AddPart.java`)

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by full stack trace, but line 55 is:                                              if (this.switchfield.getSelectedToggle().equals(this.addPartInHouse)) {

Comment: debug or add printouts to see exactly what variable is null.

Comment: Im completely new to that how can I locate what is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer but it is more readable as an answer than as a comment.

Either `switchfield` is null or `switchfield.getSelectedToggle()` returns null.

Add the following line of code **before** line 55.

```java
System.out.println(switchfield)
```

Then run your code. If it shows that `switchfield` is not null, then change it to

```java
System.out.println(switchfield.getSelectedToggle())
```

And run the code again.
That should show that `switchfield.getSelectedToggle()` returns null.

Then you need to look at the code for method `getSelectedToggle()` in class `ToggleGroup` and see when that method returns null.

My guess is that method `addPartSaveButton()` is being called before you have selected one of the radio buttons.

Comment: That looks to be it, when I select the outSource radio it forces the toggle to go Null, then I assume it just never makes it to the else statement?

Comment: Thank you that helped tremendously I changed line 54 to 'if (addPartInHouse.isSelected())' and that fixed everything.

Comment: @KyleMorgan thank you for accepting my [pseudo] answer and thanks for adding the comments explaining how it helped solve your problem.